# jQuery: two <button> in one form problem

Tags: jquery

I have two `<button>` elements in one form.
First `<button>` have a click handler, which removes the form.
Second `<button>` have click handler which submits the form.

Everything is fine, until i press `enter` inside any input field in the form. It's triggering first `<button>` and removes the form instead of submitting it.

Is it possible to fix it somehow?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the button which submits the form to `<button type="submit">` and the other to `<button type="button">` should do the trick

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/pgamE/3/

Comment: @Šime Vidas I beg to differ: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp Quote: _Always specify the type attribute for the button. The default type for Internet Explorer is "button", while in other browsers (and in the W3C specification) it is "submit"._

Comment: You're right. Although, I flinched when I saw the W3 Schools link `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You can call preventDefault() on pressing key on inputs, something like this:

```
$('input[type="button"]').keypess(function (e) { 
    var kk = navigator.appName == 'Netscape' ? e.which : e.keyCode;
    if (kk == 13) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
    }
});
```